# Converting Cassandra blob to text

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I need to convert cassandra blob to text. We are using Java and would like to integrate with other test cases I built using TestNG.

Any thoughts would be a great help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use built-in function blobAsText() as mentioned in below docs

SELECT event_id, 
  dateOf(created_at) AS creation_date,
  blobAsText(content) AS content 
  FROM timeline;

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html